# The program has unexpectedly finished - QT creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am trying to use QT creator to develop GUI/Console applications using QT framework. I am using windows XP. I installed QT 4.8.3 and mingw. Both are installed without any error. 
And then I installed QT creator. 
     QT Version: Qt 4.8.2 in PATH (4.8.2)
     Mingw(manual)
     Compiler path: C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe
     Debugger path: C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe
     mkspec:        win32-g++

```
 EnvironmentVariables:
 QTDIR, PATH, MinGW, 
 PATH includes 4.8.2\bin; mingw\bin 
 INCLUDE : 4.8.2\include
```

When i try to develop an application using qt creator, it has been built properly and binary is also generated without any error. 
But when I try to run the application, It is crashed saying that

The program has unexpectedly finished.
  C:\Qt\4.8.2\examples\widgets\analogclock-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_2_in_PATH__4_8_2__Debug\debug\analogclock.exe exited with code -1073741819

This crash came for example application provided by QT library( it is analog clock)

Please try to help me in this, Do  I need to set any variables or other

Thank alot.

Comment: try to run in debugging mode (just below the run button) and see if you get an error msg else it may be problem of DLL's

Comment: Did you try to run your program directly from the command line instead of Qt Creator?

Comment: Is there Qt dlls in your path from some other Qt version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and solved it yesterday.

If the output of `g++ --version` doesn't say something like `4.4`, this is binary incompatibility. You'll have to get MinGW 4.4. It is included in QtSDK, or at least was.
Next, configure your QtCreator settings ("Build & Run > Toolchains").

Comment: If this fixed your problem, don't forget to accept the anwser with green tick button. By the way, remember to choose python-enabled gdb during configuring toolchain, or your debugger will crash during the startup of debugging session. Good luck with Qt programming ;)