# Qt4 program unexpectedly finished (exited with code -1073741819)

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using Qt4.8.5(MinGW opensource) + QtCreator2.8.1, just while I'm trying the first "Hello Qt" sample code below, it returns the error:

> The program has unexpectedly finished.
>
> …\HelloQt.exe exited with code -1073741819

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("Hello Qt!");
    label->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Posts said that this error is caused by mistakes such as accessing invalid memories or so, but I don't think this sample code does so?

I've been trapped here for a long time.
Gratitude for any help :-)

**EDIT:**

After trails and errors, I decide to turn to Qt5.1.1 with VS2012 now. Thanks very much for the replies!

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541060/the-program-has-unexpectedly-finished-qt-creator) suggested that the reason may lies in the incompatibility between the MinGW and Qt, after replace the old MinGW with the recommended [MinGW-gcc440](http://dldx.csdn.net/fd.php?i=707048635856451&s=1f8a9e81d72d9c7a679ad1bd2e720aa3) the error code changed to -1073741511 which may means the unaccessible to .dll s.

So I followed another post and use the MinGw-gcc4.4.0 to compile the source of Qt, but finally, after hours of compiling, it stopped with error T_T

That's all, thank you.

Comment: Did you press the red stop button in QtCreator? This "kills" your application, which is interpreted in "unexpectedly finished" by QtCreator. Does this happen if you close the label window with its close button?

Comment: It is an access violation, you'll get them when you use a library in a completely unexpected way.  You really do need to start at "Hello world", that doesn't look like this code.  The obvious google query is "qt hello world".  Take the first hit and start reading.

Comment: @leemes Thanks, I see the button, but I didn't press it. I just click the green triangle.

Comment: @HansPassant I just follow through that post [link](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_for_beginners_Hello_World) but the problem turns out to be still there... But that's really a clear guide, as a beginner, I didn't pay attention to the .pro file :-)

Comment: The last time I had this error, my *Qt Creator kit* was configured with the wrong compiler by default (compiler provided with Strawberry Perl). I had to create another kit with the good MinGW compiler.

Comment: Please check if in your `.pro` file qt is not configured as console, e.g. `QT += console` should not be there, and `QT += gui` or `QT += widgets` if qt version >= 5.0 should be there. This behavior is definitely sounds like only console app selected and you try to show GUI

Comment: Shf: All that would already fail at compile/link time, not at runtime

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld yeah, you are right, with 'undefined references' messages

Comment: Thank you very much for offering helps. :-D

Answer (score 0):

(for Windows) I must say that it goes much more smoothly to use Qt5.1.1 & VisualStudio2012. So I will post the essential steps here hoping to help someone :-)

1. Already have vs2012.
2. download and install [qt-windows-opensource-5.1.1-msvc2012-x86_64-offline.exe](http://mirrors.hustunique.com/qt/official_releases/qt/5.1/5.1.1/qt-windows-opensource-5.1.1-msvc2012-x86_64-offline.exe).
3. download and install [qt-vs-addin-1.2.2-opensource.exe](http://mirrors.hustunique.com/qt/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.2.2-opensource.exe).
4. (necessary) Set a new system Path "QTDIR" = "D:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012_64"

The 4th step is important because the %QTDIR% is the prefix of paths used by VisualStudio to find libraries included.

That's all now you can start a new Qt Project.